# Electron fix "ERROR:buffer_manager.cc(488)] [.DisplayCompositor]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glBufferData: <- error from previous GL command"

Tags: electron

I recently stepped down my electron application removed `knex` and `sqlite` since it was painfully complicated to creating a rebuild on windows also when i made an executable for windows `sqlite` database didn't seem to work. Linux executable worked fine with `sqlite` guessing the same with mac.

To use `sqlite` i had rebuilt the application using `electron-rebuild`. In order to clear the rebuild i did `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`

I have eventually decided to use IndexDB using `dexie`.

**However now when i try to run my program from npm i get**

> ERROR:buffer_manager.cc(488)] [.DisplayCompositor]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glBufferData: <- error from previous GL command

How do i fix this, why is it happening ?

*NB: The application works just fine but this error i the terminal is just annoying and i have no idea why its happenning*

Comment: Which distro and hardware do you use? I met same error with Visual Studio Code on Arch Linux. I'm tried intel 10510u with integrated graphic and Nvidia mx250 - same thing.
I assume it's bug in electron's render or Arch's openGL implementation.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Do a test,

`electron /path/to/the/app` [You will get that Error]

Try

`electron --disable-gpu /path/to/the/app` [You mayn't get that Error]

> The fix was to add "--disable-gpu" to the command-line to force the
>   web view not to use gpu features. I was able to accomplish this in an
>   electron app by editing the package.json file in app root and changing
>   the line like "start": "electron ." to "start": "electron .
>   --disable-gpu"

Refer https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/7834#issuecomment-275802528

Comment: @xaander1 I guess the issue is with the chromium component of electron using the GPU to do HW Acceleration [Mayn't be accurate]. You will get the same error if you open google-chrome/chromium from a terminal.

Comment: I couldn't execute `electron /path/to/the/app` because it said `electron command not found`. But changing `electron .` in package.json to `electron . --disable-gpu` does in fact fixes the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Based on Sudhakar RS answer , I made a script in my package.json  to not use GL

here is my package.json

```
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron --disable-gpu .", // --disable GL ERROR and use CPU
    ...
  }
 ...

}
```

Then in your terminal run

```
npm run start
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution for issue:
"dev": ".electron-vue/dev-runner.js --disable-gpu"

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error running [electron-quick-start](https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start) but not when running [electron-boilerplate](https://github.com/sindresorhus/electron-boilerplate).

Investigating the error I found this question and for me also, starting with "electron --disable-gpu ." prevents the error message. But I didn't have to do that with electron-boilerplate. So, comparing the two I traced the difference to the inclusion of electron-debug in electron-boilerplate and, ultimately, to this: process.stderr.fd.

Thus far, the minimal change I have found sufficient to avoid the error is:

```
diff --git a/main.js b/main.js
index 3508c8e..7df262b 100644
--- a/main.js
+++ b/main.js
@@ -2,6 +2,8 @@
 const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron')
 const path = require('path')

+process.stderr.fd;
+
 // Keep a global reference of the window object, if you don't, the window will
 // be closed automatically when the JavaScript object is garbage collected.
 let mainWindow
```

So, now I am trying to understand what `process.stderr.fd;` does and how it prevents the error message from appearing. It seems odd that merely getting the file descriptor of stderr would prevent the error but evidently it does.

I am also curious about the relative merits of disabling the GPU Vs getting the file descriptor.

edit: it is sufficient to get the stream with `process.stderr;` it is not necessary to get the file descriptor.

Comment: This is next level. No clue why it helps but I can confirm it helps.